# IDs length in map2SpatialPolygons

Tags: r, dictionary, geospatial

I knew that this function could work in another case but it does not work in this code.

So here is a dbf file and a shapefile(county), I would like to link the dbf file to the shapefile (just like join in ArcGIS). That's the county.countypf has same set of value as the data.countyfp. This step is to set one field(COUNTYFP) as the primary key by using map2SpatialPolygons function.

Here is my code.

```
county <- readShapeSpatial("county")
data<- read.dbf("data",as.is = FALSE)`

map.county <- map("county", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE, res=0)
map.IDs <- sapply(county$COUNTYFP, function(x) x[1])
tail(map.IDs)

county <- map2SpatialPolygons(map.county, 
                              IDs = map.IDs,
                              proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
```

I set the fill as T so that it could return polygon, but the IDs and map do not have the same length as well.
The error shows

> "Error in map2SpatialPolygons(map.county, IDs = map.IDs, proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")) : map and IDs differ in length"

Comment: give an example data and write what is the exact problem you have

Answer (score 1):

Like it says, "map and IDs differ in length". `IDs` should be related to 'map.county', which you'd like to convert to 'SpatialPolygons' in the first place. When performing `map("county", ...)`, this does not refer to the initially created variable 'county', but to the USA database that comes with the **maps** package (see `?map` for further reading). I don't know exactly what's stored in 'county', but if I had to guess, I'd say it's length is different from 'map.county'. Therefore, your code should e.g. look as follows.

```
## required packages
library(maps)
library(maptools)

## geographical map of us counties
map.county <- map("county", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE, res = 0)

## convert 'map' to 'SpatialPolygons'
county <- map2SpatialPolygons(map.county, 
                              IDs = map.county$names,
                              proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
```